# JavaScript countdown timer will not display twice

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following JavaScript count down timer, which I got from a post on Stackoverflow:

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var start = Date.now(),
        diff,
        minutes,
        seconds;
    function timer() {
        diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

        minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
        seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds; 

        if (diff <= 0) {
            start = Date.now() + 1000;
        }
    };

    timer();
    setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

and I use the following HTML to display it:

```
<div class="timerConatiner">
    <div class="countDownTimer"><span id="time"></span></div>
</div>
```

The webpage I am using is responsive and the position of the time greatly changes depending on screen size.

So the best way I can think of to achieve this is to have 2 versions of the timer in the HTML and then set one to `display:none` and the other to  `display:block` using CSS, depending on which one I want to display.

The problem is that only the first one declared in the HTML will display, and the other one will never be visible. The second one does not even exist on the webpage as it does not show up in the DOM explorer.

I have tried creating 2 timers with separate id's eg:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
        display = document.querySelector('#time1');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

but this does not work.

Does anyone know the reason this is happening? I would expect that when I create 2 versions with separate ids, they would both display, but obviously they don't?

I am sure I could create 2 versions of the timer but this does not seem very elegant.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with two onload functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works really good i guess oO
Added second div with span and modified your onload function a lottile bit ;)

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var start = Date.now(),
        diff,
        minutes,
        seconds;
    function timer() {
        diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

        minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
        seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds; 

        if (diff <= 0) {
            start = Date.now() + 1000;
        }
    };

    timer();
    setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

function toggle(){
  if (document.getElementById("time").style.visibility == "hidden"){
    document.getElementById("time").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("time2").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }else{
    document.getElementById("time2").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("time").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5;
    var tenMinutes = 60 * 10;    
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
    display = document.querySelector('#time2');
    startTimer(tenMinutes, display);
    
};
```

```html
<div class="timerConatiner">
    <div class="countDownTimer"><span id="time"></span></div>
    <div class="countDownTimer2"><span id="time2" style ="visibility: hidden"></span></div>
</div>
<input type = "button" onclick = "toggle()" value = "Toggle"></input>
```